# Запрос данных из нескольких таблиц с одинаковыми полями

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим есть 2 таблицы , у них есть одинаковые поля `id, id_product`, далее произвольное количество полей , например таблица `table_10` поля ->`id,id_product, еще 3 поля` и таблица `table_11` поля -> `id,id_product, еще 2 поля`. Нужно получить все поля из определенной таблицы по одному идентификатору `id`.
Пишу запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_11 UNION SELECT * FROM table_10) as t WHERE t.id = 20
```

Соответственно он не работает. Я могу вывести например какое то определенное количество полей, но как вывести все поля ?

Comment: Количество столбцов в объединяемых таблицах должно быть одинаковым. Значит нужно либо добавить в одну таблицу, либо убрать из другой.

Comment: перечислите все поля, там где полей оказалось меньше, напишите вместо них NULL

Comment: Это как то сложно добавлять колонки как по мне, решил пока что сделать так -> id в table_10 и 11 уникальны и не могут совпасть друг с другом, по этому просто сделал 2 запроса select* from table_11 where id = 20; select* from table_10 where id = 20 , решение такое конечно, выглядит не очень, но с задачей справляется

Answer (score 1):

Правильней будет перечислить все необходимые поля, причём их число и тип в обоих частях `UNION` должны совпадать.

Но если все кроме нескольких полей в обоих таблицах совпадают, то можно сдаелать так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t10.* FROM table_10 as t10
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t11.*, 'NONE' f FROM table_11 as t11 
) as t WHERE t.id = 20
```

Вместо `'NONE'` можно использовать значение в зависимости от типа поля: `0`, `NULL` и т.д.